# Is there still any laptop with default OS WinXP on it?

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, operating-systems

Trying to get a new laptop, but it seems most of them are running on Win7. I was wondering are there still some laptops that come with WinXP or provide XP drivers for downgrade to WinXP? Thanks.

Comment: To the best of my (limited) knowledge Microsoft will not allow OEMs to ship new machines with XP on them. Getting one for a relative a couple of years ago was a hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very few provide that still. Dell continues to offer XP preinstalled on some of their corporate laptops by using downgrade rights from Windows 7. [Two Vostro models](http://www.dell.com/us/en/business/notebooks/vostronb/ct.aspx?refid=vostronb&s=bsd&cs=04&ref=lthp) and almost all [Latitude models](http://www.dell.com/us/en/business/notebooks/latitude/ct.aspx?refid=latit&s=bsd&cs=04&ref=lthp) are listed as having the XP downgrade option (click the "compare" button to see the charts).

Netbooks are still permitted to be sold with a Windows XP Home license, but only for a few more months. In terms of licensing, any computer with Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate can be legally downgraded to Windows XP Professional. Driver support is variable though.